# How to add widget by a function in kivymd

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Hiii,

I am a beginner in kivymd and python.

I am working on my new app and got stuck at this point.. where i want to add some widgets by using a function but it throws an error..

i don't know what's wrong with it ..
it gave me this error :

`File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kivy/uix/gridlayout.py", line 307, in on_children raise GridLayoutException( kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayoutException: Too many children in GridLayout. Increase rows/cols!`

i just want to add one widget but it saying "too many children in GridLayout"

i can't understand what it means
please explain me this.

```
import kivymd
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.relativelayout import MDRelativeLayout
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

from kivy.core.text import LabelBase



kv = '''

bseb_layout:
    
    screen_mngr: screen_mngr
    
    MDScreenManager:
        id: screen_mngr
        subjects: subjects
        chapter_list: chapter_list
        

#======================================================



#===================subjects===========================
        
        MDScreen:
            id: subjects
            name: "subjects"
                
            
            
            MDLabel:
                text: "Question Bank\\n10 Years"
                font_size: "30dp"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.42}
            
            MDLabel:
                text: "Chapter-wise"
                font_size: "20dp"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.35}
            
            
            MDCard:
                size_hint: 0.45,0.4
                pos_hint: {"x":0.025, "y": 0.4}
                md_bg_color: 1,0,1,0.2
                radius: 25,25,25,25
                on_press: app.func()
                on_press: root.screen_mngr.current = "chapter_list"
                
                MDRelativeLayout:
                    
       
                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Physics"
                        font_size: "25dp"
                        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "y": 0}
            
            MDCard:
                size_hint: 0.45,0.3
                pos_hint: {"x":0.525, "y": 0.5}
                md_bg_color: 1,0,1,0.2
                radius: 25,25,25,25
                on_press: print('Works')
                
                MDRelativeLayout:
                    
                
                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "chemistry"
                        font_size: "25dp"
                        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "y": 0}
            
            MDCard:
                size_hint: 0.45,0.3
                pos_hint: {"x":0.025, "y": 0.05}
                md_bg_color: 1,0,1,0.2
                radius: 25,25,25,25
                on_press: print('Works')
                
                MDRelativeLayout:
                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "English"
                        font_size: "25dp"
                        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "y": 0}
            
            MDCard:
                size_hint: 0.45,0.4
                pos_hint: {"x":0.525, "y": 0.05}
                md_bg_color: 1,0,1,0.2
                radius: 25,25,25,25
                on_press: print('Works')
                
                MDRelativeLayout:
                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text: "Biology"
                        font_size: "25dp"
                        pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "y": 0}

#===================subjects-END=======================





#=================chapter_list=========================
        MDScreen:
            id: chapter_list
            name: "chapter_list"
            chapter_grid: chapter_grid
            
            FitImage:
                source: "grad3.jpg"
            
            MDLabel:
                text: "Phsycis\\nChapters"
                font_size: "30dp"
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.42}
            
            MDScrollView:
                id: location
                md_bg_color: 1,1,1,0.1
                size_hint: 0.95,0.03
                pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"y": 0.83}
                do_scroll_x: True
                do_scroll_y: False
                radius: 25,25,25,25
                bar_color: 214/255, 99/255, 168/255,0.5
                bar_inactive_color: 1,1,1,0
                                                
                MDGridLayout:
                    id: chapter_grid
                    adaptive_height: True
                    adaptive_width: True
                    cols: 1
                    rows:1
                    padding: ("20dp","0dp")
                    
                    
                    MDCard:
                        size_hint: None,None
                        size: "350dp","15dp"
                        md_bg_color: 1,0,1,0.2
                        MDRelativeLayout:
            
                            MDLabel:
                                text: "Physics > 2023 > Chapters"
                                font_size: "15dp"
                                pos_hint: {"x": 0.0, "center_y": 0.5}
            
            
            MDScrollView:
                md_bg_color: 1,1,1,0.2
                size_hint: 0.95,0.8
                pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"y": 0.02}
                do_scroll_x: False
                radius: 25,25,25,25
                bar_color: 214/255, 99/255, 168/255,0.5
                bar_inactive_color: 1,1,1,0
                
                MDGridLayout:
                    adaptive_height: True
                    adaptive_width: True
                    cols: 1
                    padding: ("11dp","10dp")
                    spacing: "10dp"
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    MDCard:
                        size_hint: None,None
                        size: "320dp", "60dp"
                        md_bg_color: 1,0,1,0.2
                        radius: 25,25,25,25
                        on_press: print('Works')
                        
                        MDRelativeLayout:
                            
                            MDLabel:
                                text: "Electrostatics"
                                font_size: "20dp"
                                pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.5}
                    
                    
        
        
        
        
#==================chapter_list-END====================


            
                        
                
'''

class bseb_layout(FloatLayout):

    pass


class bseb(MDApp):
    
    
    def func(self):

        
        self.root.ids.screen_mngr.chapter_list.chapter_grid.add_widget(
            MDCard(
                
            
                MDRelativeLayout(
                
                MDLabel(
                    text="chapter_2",
                    font_size="20dp",
                    theme_text_color="Custom",
                    text_color=(1,1,1,1),
                    pos_hint={"x":0.1,"center_y":0.5}
            )
        ),
            size_hint=(None,None),
            size=("320dp","60dp"),
            md_bg_color=(1,1,1,0.2),
            radius=(25,25,25,25),
    )
    )
    
    
    
    
    
    def build(self):
        
        return Builder.load_string(kv)




if __name__=="__main__":
        bseb().run()
```

Any help is much appreciated...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
            MDGridLayout:
                id: chapter_grid
                adaptive_height: True
                adaptive_width: True
                cols: 1
                rows:1
```

Limits that `MDGridLayout` to exactly one column and one row. That means that it can only have one child widget. If you want to allow more than one row, then remove the `rows: 1`, or, if you want more than one column, remove the `cols: 1`. But you cannot remove both. You must specify one of `rows:` or `cols:`.

Comment: thank you so much mate. I am so so dumb,  . that GridLayout with 1 col and 1 row was the wrong GridLayout i was supposed to do it with the next GridLayout . Anyways Thank you very much. ✨❤️